# Fill Shapes automatically with 5~ colors randomly in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have a mosaic of shapes fitted together in Illustrator however currently they're all black and white.

For example:

[image]

However, I've already got a series of colors that I want to use to fill each of the shapes in a random order (preferably without two colors being next to each other) so that it looks something like:

For example:

[image]

The mosaic is 250+ pieces in my first file and my second file has 800+ pieces.

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
   This script performs random color fill.
   Select art items and colors in swatches panel and run script.
   Note: neighbor art items can get the same colors.
*/
var doc = app.activeDocument;
var selItems = doc.selection;
var sw_sel = doc.swatches.getSelected();
if (sw_sel.lenght==0 )
    exit;

for (var i=0; i<selItems.length; i++)
{
    var selItem = selItems[i];
    if(selItem.typename == "PathItem"   || 
        selItem.typename == "CompoundPathItem")
    {
        var randomColorIdx = getRandom(0, sw_sel.length - 1);
        setColor(selItem, sw_sel[randomColorIdx].color);                
    }
}

function setColor(pItem, color)
{
   pItem.filled = true;
   if(pItem.typename == "PathItem")
            pItem.fillColor = color;
    else
        pItem.pathItems[0].fillColor = color;    
}

function getRandom(min, max)
{
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few plugins and scripts that can accomplish this.

[Randomill](https://randomill.com) is one such plugin and robotwood's ['Random Swatches Fill' script](https://github.com/robotwood/Random-Swatch-Fill) is another. With either one of these, you can use swatches from the swatches panel and randomly apply them to a set of objects.